# Bat/Shell file copy to Unix/Windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix, scripting, batch-file

I got the task to write a script to do some tasks, one of those is to copy some files from the local machine to a server directory.
Now this isn't exactly my area of expertise, so I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice/pointers.

They gave me the following requirements:
1) same script needs to be capable of copying to a Windows AND Unix machine
2) no files should be modified (such as .rhost)
3) Bat file for the Windows machines, Shell script for the Unix machines

It doesn't matter if I read whether the target machine is Windows/Unix from the command line so an if/else is possible.

But I have no idea on how to start with this without having to modify the rhost file so any input is appreciated.

Comment: What OS is the server running? Can you install any software on it? Can you install any software on the clients? (Also, .rhosts? Dear $deity, do people *still* use that?)

Comment: How is the server "connected" to your local machine? FTP? Windows share? HTTP? sneakernet?

Comment: OS on the "server" (maybe target would have been more apt): Unix, Linux(Suse) or Windows XP. And "connected": same internal network. How I do it is up to me as long as I follow those instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it as internal network (= security assumptions aside) I would set up a FTP server on the server side and use [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) on the client side to connect to the server.

Comment: Would be a nice solution, but setting up an FTP server on every developer machine might be an issue.

Comment: @Jack IMHO it will not work without doing anything on the developer machines, because every machine is normally secured to outside access. What do you exactly wanna do? What kind of files do you wanna copy?

Comment: Copy some jar files, might have to look into an app that adds the scp command to windows. I think that has the highest chance of being allowed.

Comment: Jar files? You want to update a Java application? How about Java webstart then?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like `scp` or `sftp` (the SSH tools for file transfer)?  They are cross-platform, but you will need to set up keys and an SSH server on the destination of the transfer.

Comment: The trouble is that it should also work on local developer machines, so setting up an SSH server doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: @Jack: You have no idea how easy it is to set up SSH on a Linux system.

Comment: It is easy, but I work with some really lazy people who already complain about having to change 1 thing.

Answer (score 0):

From any to any:

- CIFS, aka Windows File Sharing. Built-in to Windows; requires `samba` server or `smbclient` client on Linux. Easy to configure.
- FTP - Windows comes with a scriptable `ftp` tool, a similar one exists on Linux. For single-file uploads, however, `curl` is much easier to use.
- WebDAV: Can be accessed from Windows in the same way as CIFS shares, and server software exists for both OSes (Apache2 with mod_dav).

From any to Linux:

- SFTP, which runs over the SSH protocol. The PuTTY SSH client comes with two SFTP clients, `psftp` and `pscp`. On Linux, the server (OpenSSH) is usually installed by default.

  (Windows SSH servers exist, but... I don't like them. I don't even know why.)